# How to accept an Array payload not on a Model table in DjangoRestFramework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

When the code below was ran, I got a **'create' method not implemented error.** How do I create a create method on a model that doesn't have an applicant field. What's the best way to handle this?

Payload data (as in POSTMAN):

```
    {
      "applicants": [{"id": 1, "status": 2}, {"id": 12, "status": 3}, 
      {"id": 11, "status": 2}]
    }
```

My serializers.py file:

```
class StringListField(serializers.ListField):
    applicants = serializers.CharField

class UpdateApplicantSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    applicants = StringListField()
```

Models.py file:

```
class Applicant(models.Model):

    APPLICATION_STATUS = (
      (1, 'Pending'),
      (2, 'Accept'),
      (3, 'Reject'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, 
    null=False)

    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, 
    null=False)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, 
    unique=True)

    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', 
    message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. 
    Up to 15 digits allowed.")

    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], 
    max_length=17, blank=True, null=False, unique=True) # validators 
    should be a list

    linkedin_url = models.URLField(max_length=255, unique=True) #make 
    sure diff users cant use two same profile

    twitter_url = models.URLField(max_length=255, unique=True) #make 
    sure diff users cant use two same profile

    articles = ArrayField(models.URLField(), blank=False, null=False, 
    unique=True, size=3)

    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    blank=False, related_name="applicant")

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name="applicant", blank=False)

    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, 
      choices=APPLICATION_STATUS, default=1)
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with array payloads or the existence of an applicant field. The error tells you exactly what is wrong: your view does not have a create method.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman, I added a create method to the class:

'def create(self, validated_data):
        return Applicant.objects.create(**validated_data)'

And I get this error: 

**TypeError: applicants is an invalid keyword argument for this function**

Comment: Presumably you are trying to update these applicants, not create them, given you are sending the existing id of each applicant along with the status?

Comment: Yes @WillKeeling, my intention is to update the applicant status using their ID.

Comment: You would normally send a PATCH request for updating objects. A POST request is used for creating them. You can set the method to PATCH in Postman. Can you post your full views.py?